# How to open all Bootstrap accordion tabs at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following accordian and would like to allow the user to expand all accordian tabs on the click of a button using jQuery.

I've tried using this method (https://codepen.io/dikuw/pen/KgzvJp) but the accordion is within a Kendo custom edit template popup and instead of expanding all of the panels, it just toggles the opening of the first and second panel.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-demo" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#prerequisites" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="prerequisites">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="prerequisites" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="prerequisites">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed panel-title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#addwizard" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="addwizard">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="addwizard" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addwizard">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed panel-title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#adjusthtml" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="adjusthtml">
                                Collapsible Group Item #3
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="adjusthtml" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="adjusthtml">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you using angularjs for this ? because example you have mentioned is in angularjs .

Comment: I don't believe so. All I want to be able to do is expand the panels that aren't already visible when the user clicks a button.

I'm confused as to why this isn't working:

$('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
.collapse('show');

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.closeall').click(function () {
          $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});


  $('.openall').click(function () {
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <a class="btn btn-primary openall" href="#">open all</a> <a class="btn btn-danger closeall" href="#">close all</a>
<hr>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        #1 Expanded
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
          #2 Expanded
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
         #3 Expanded
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in your code snippet.

If you open #2 and click expand all, it closes #2 and opens #1

Comment: This works fine! However, you should use `event.preventDefault()` on the click event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open/close the accordion **animated**, you can use the bootstrap hide and show functions. The bootstrap 5.2 [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#options) is correct, but it still took me a few tries to get it working properly. It seems you have to stop the toggle in the config for each collapsible:

```
$(".closeall").on('click', function () {
    $('#myAccordion .collapse').each(function(){
        new bootstrap.Collapse(this,{ toggle: false }).hide();
    });
});
$(".openall").on('click', function () {
    $('#myAccordion .collapse').each(function(){
        new bootstrap.Collapse(this,{ toggle: false }).show();
    });
});
```

If you omit the { toggle: false } it doesn't matter what function you call, it will always toggle each collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-default openall" href="#">open all</a> <a class="btn btn-default closeall" href="#">close all</a>
        <hr>
       <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-demo" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#prerequisites" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="prerequisites">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="prerequisites" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="prerequisites">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed panel-title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#addwizard" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="addwizard">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="addwizard" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addwizard">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed panel-title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#adjusthtml" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="adjusthtml">
                                Collapsible Group Item #3
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="adjusthtml" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="adjusthtml">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

----javascript---code

```
$('.closeall').click(function () {
        $('.panel-collapse.in')
          .collapse('hide');
    });
    $('.openall').click(function () {
        $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
          .collapse('show');
    });
```

this worked for me in codepen which you gave..

Comment: It doesn't work though.

If you open #2 and click expand all, it closes #2 and opens #1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in bootstrap 5

```
$(".closeall").click(function () {
    $(".collapse").removeClass("show");
});
$(".openall").click(function () {
    $(".collapse").addClass("show");
});
```